How to fix my cloth behaving wierdly?
I use cloth simulations for a short time and now I have second issue with them (in the same project). This time when I made a test animation of my character lowering its arm and the cloth started to break in various ways: it accumulates on both sides, it rips apart (I use sewing) and so on...

Please help! Here's the file: 

Is this a dummy or the actual model to animate? I wonder because it has a rather messy topology. Blender's sewing does not merge the mesh parts automatically, but you can collapse the sewing edges manually.

This is a model, that I want to animate. Yeah, the typology is not great, but it's because I'm not experienced enough. Anyways, thanks for an answer. I'll try to make the edges manually.
